# Push Message not received when App was in Airplain Mode

Tags: xamarin.ios, azure-mobile-services

Today I tested if a sent push message gets received when I connect back to internet but I did not receive it.

**My Test Case:**

1. Activate Airplain Mode
2. Send Push Message
3. Deactivate Airplain Mode, connected back to Internet

**Expected Behaviour:**
Get Push Message

**Actual Behaviour:**
Nothing received

I use a Push Notification Hub that is connected to my Azure Mobile Apps Backend.

**Edit:** Sometimes the Push Message arrives, sometimes not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is expected behavior.  Push notifications do not get queued by the various providers in general.  They expire, usually relatively quickly.

Comment: Is there any good solution to overcome that. I need that Push Messages to invoke a PullAsync request. One way would be to do that in the PhoneConnectivity event.

Comment: You should trap the connectivity event and sync when you come back online.

Comment: That event  I have already implemented. I am very suprised that in the Droid app the push messages get received in the same scenario. So there must be a kind of queueing in the Push Notification Hub, otherwise those messages would be dropped. I tested it several times as discribed above on the Xamarin.Forms Android app, and on reconnection to the Web, I got the pushed messages.

Comment: Maybe lucky punches